# Set Internet-Explorer Homepage "once" via GPO

Tags: internet-explorer-10, gpo

I want to set a Homepage via GPO. I know this can be done in

Preferences\Control Panel Settings\Internet Settings

The problem is that if I change the standard Homepage there it will always set it to that page after every logon, regardless if the user changes the homepage in the meantime.

I however want that it is only set once (i.e. google.com) and if the users changes it (i.e. to bing.com) it should stay on bing.

Can you tell me how this can be done?

Edit:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822332.aspx

"Group Policy preferences. You can use Group Policy preference settings to configure options that users can change later."

This is actually what I want to do. I set a preference and then the user can change it to something else later. However - setting it works fine, changing it too but after logout/login it is back to where it was before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution - it's surprising how difficult it was to find by googling. In the end I just stumbled over it by checking the policies again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> if I change the standard Homepage there it will always set it to that page ...
> I however want that it is only set once
>
> Can you tell me how this can be done?

Not at all. What you want to do is self-contradictional.

"Standard XYZ" means that XYZ will be done every time, and "XYZ only once" is the exact opposite.

Comment: Well - that's the issue I am trying to solve. I want to set a default homepage BUT if the user likes to change it, he can do so and my setting will be discarded.

Comment: What I was searching for was the "apply once" setting.